# CSS Dropdown pushes content down page

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

This is a simple dropdown menu.  It's a free template that uses webkit (only learning about what this is).  I'm not very good with CSS and I can change so that the dropdown menu will not push the other content down the page, but this creates other problems.

The other problems being that the background of the dropdown menu is no longer red, but transparent and the transition doesn't work.

Additionally, even with a transparent background, when I hover over the dropdown menu, I cannot hover over the entire list without the menu collapsing. For example, in the list below, there are 4 items, Basic, Basic Plus, Ultra, and Ultra Plus.  When I've set the **ul** to *position:relative* the menu no longer pushes the rest of the content down the page, but when I try to hover over Ultra, the menu goes away.

Here is where I'm developing it:

http://www.oklahomastepparentadoption.com/truck-web/index.php

I really like how the transition works on the entire drop down menu (slide down from the top).

This is the CSS code (HTML below)

```
.top-nav{
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
}
.top-nav ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.top-nav ul  li{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18%;
  margin-right: .4em;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.top-nav ul  li.active{
      background: #bb1e10;
}

.top-nav ul li a{
color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-right: .4em;
  float: left;
  padding: 1em 0em 1em 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 79%;
}
.top-nav ul li a i{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.top-nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    left:0;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.top-nav ul ul li {
    float:none;
    width:200px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.top-nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 5px 5px;
}
.top-nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
```

HTML CODE:

```
            <div class="top-nav">
                <span class="menu"><img src="images/menu.png" alt=""></span>

                <ul class="nav1" style="margin-top: .5em;">
                    <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom" style="width:22%;"><a href="fleet.php" style="padding-top:0.25em; padding-bottom:.35em;">Fleet Management</a>
                        <ul class="level_1">
                            <li><a href="#">Basic</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Basic Plus</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ultra</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ultra Plus</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><a href="services.php" style="padding-top:0.25em; padding-bottom:.35em;">Broker Agency</a></li>
                    <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><a href="blog.php">Drivers</a></li>
                    <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><a href="mail.php">Contact</a></li>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `position: absolute` to the menu. Also make sure to update the `top` and `background`:

```css
.top-nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    /* Changes below */
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 62px;
    background: #bb1e10;
}
```

**Preview**

[image: before]

[image: after]

---

**Update**

Add this to the `.header`:

```
.header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Fixes the last links:

[image: preview]

Comment: Please visit the webpage again.  I've added .top-nav {position: absolute;} and of course it doesn't push the content down, but I can't hover over the last 2 links on the dropdown menu.

Comment: @j_allen_morris Did you add all the other properties as well? I updated my answer.

Comment: @j_allen_morris Check the updated answer. It works now.

Comment: .header in which file?  There is no class of .header in the style.css file.

Comment: @j_allen_morris Add new... :) Just copy the new set of CSS and put it at the end of your CSS file.

Comment: uploading...CuteFTP crashed.  :(

Comment: @j_allen_morris If you are using Windows, I suggest you to go for WinSCP. Awesome one, no regrets after migrating from CuteFTP Pro.

Comment: I'll check it out.  I've gotten used to CuteFTP over the years and am used to it.  Adding the .header like you suggested fixed it.  I'll select your answer.  Thank you so much.  I'd been working and working and working on this.  I like CSS but i also hate it.  lol

Comment: @j_allen_morris CSS is heaven. Ask me anything if you need in CSS. :D

Comment: I do have another question about CSS.  Is there a PM feature on here?

Comment: @j_allen_morris ^ Here... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as Praveen says, you need to make the nav absolutely positioned. Make sure though, the container 'header' is relative positioned, else it will fill 40% of the whole screen.

check out this fiddle to see what i mean: https://jsfiddle.net/ho2sph79/

```
.header {
    position:relative;
}
.top-nav {
    position:absolute;
    width:40%;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: I'll add  position:absolute, but I think it's going to mess up the dropdown and make it where I cannot click on the last few links of the dropdown menu.

Comment: I added it as you said.  Please go to my website link above and check it out.  It messed up the location of the men (which I'm pretty sure I can fix) but the menu collapses before I can hover over the last few links in the dropdown menu.

Comment: Hi, the drop down menu needs to position absolute as well. I would suggest something like this:

.top-nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #bb1e10;
    width: 100%;
    top: 85px;
}

Answer (score 0):

you can try this http://callmenick.com/post/slide-down-menu-with-jquery-and-css and as i noticed, your css for the dropdown doesnt have any transition elements. try the link i provided it may help you out regarding transitions